# For loop working in terminal but not in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I was trying to rename files.

```
$ls
1.jpg   12.jpg  15.jpg  18.jpg  3.png  6.jpg  9.png
10.jpg  13.jpg  16.jpg  19.jpg  4.jpg  7.png
11.jpg  14.jpg  17.jpg  2.jpg   5.jpg  8.jpg
```

From `1.jpg` to `01.jpg` for files `{1..9}.*` irrespective of extension.
I tried the following `for` loop in terminal it worked perfectly.

```
$for i in {1..9}.*;do mv "$i" 0"$i";done
```

When I wrote the same in shell script it didn't work.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..9}.*;do mv "$i" 0"$i";done
```

It gave the following error

```
mv cannot stat '{1..9}.*':No such file or directory
```

I figured that posix shell doesn't support `{1..9}.*` syntax.

Q:what is the equivalent of this in posix?

-Thank You.

Comment: Try changing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the wildcard pattern `[1-9].*`.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in [1-9].*
do 
    mv "$i" 0"$i"
done
```